# How to sync mysql databases across development computers (windows): my failed attempt

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I tried using file syncing software (Syncplicity) to sync MySQL databases across two windows development computers.  I synced the entire \xampp\mysql\data folder.

All files synced properly to the second computer, and I can view the tables in phpmyadmin. However browsing a table gives error "...table doesn't exist in engine"

This would be totally cool if it worked. But it doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:  it looks like for innoDB the data is stored in a single file ibdata1, just below the directories for each database. So the /data root (and all subdirectories) should also be synced.

However this is not a great setup in the first place: Syncplicity doesn't support delta sync and the ibdata1 file can be huge. Even viewing the records with phpmyadmin changes the file which forces a full re-sync.

Naturally, syncing stations of different developers all working on the project would be a disaster.